# My case logic is returning two rows when there are at least two different values rendered

Tags: sql, case

Here is my code below. I want to show either Pass or Fail as the value for the field "Homeless" for that particular building/property/apt complex. The below code returns these rows:

```
Property   Homeless
1523cdc    Fail
1523cdc    Pass
2700       Fail
2700       Fail
```

In the building called **2700** there are 8 apts and 7 are marked Yes for the Homeless field and 1 apt is blank. In the building called **1523cdc** there are 6 apts and 1 is marked Yes for the Homeless field and the other 5 are blank.  I am trying to track he percentage of apts that are marked as Homeless - 2700 should be 100% and 1523cdc should be 16.6666%  ***I only want one row for each building, and in this example it should be 2700 Fail and 1523cdc Pass***

How can I accomplish this. Thanks :|

```
 SELECT  p.sCode "Property"
, case when (sum(case when p.scode = '2700' and unit.sfield5 = 'yes' then 1 else 0 end)) = 8 then 'Pass'
       when (sum(case when p.scode = '1523cdc' and unit.sfield5 = 'yes' then 1 else 0 end)) = 1      
       then 'Pass' else 'Fail' end as 'Homeless'
 FROM  Property p  left JOIN Unit ON (p.hMy = unit.hProperty) 
 WHERE 1 = 1
 and unit.scode not like ('b%')
 and unit.scode not like ('h%')
 and unit.scode not like ('s%')
 and unit.scode != 'HOMESPUN'
 and p.scode in ('2700','1523cdc')
 group by p.scode, unit.sfield5
 ORDER BY  p.sCode ASC
```

Comment: What SQL software do you use? and have you tried `SELECT DISTINCT`?

Comment: remove `unit.sfield5`just  `group by p.scode`

Comment: Not sure of the SQL version, it is hosted by a property management app.  I just tried select distinct ..... and got the same result.  It has to be something in the case checking the values.

Comment: Thank you Juan Carlos Oropeza that is it!!  I did have SQL errors in earlier version of my code and then, how ti always goes, I became "blinded" to searching for the answer in the case logic.  It works now!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 things:

You don't need `1=1`

you shouldn't do `group by unit.sfield5` - this produced 2 rows since you have 2 values (yes and blank)

```
SELECT  p.sCode "Property"
    , case when (sum(case when p.scode = '2700' and unit.sfield5 = 'yes' then 1 else 0 end)) = 8 then 'Pass'
           when (sum(case when p.scode = '1523cdc' and unit.sfield5 = 'yes' then 1 else 0 end)) = 1      
           then 'Pass' else 'Fail' end as 'Homeless'
 FROM  Property p  left JOIN Unit ON (p.hMy = unit.hProperty) 
 WHERE unit.scode not like ('b%')
 and unit.scode not like ('h%')
 and unit.scode not like ('s%')
 and unit.scode != 'HOMESPUN'
 and p.scode in ('2700','1523cdc')
 group by p.scode
 ORDER BY p.sCode ASC
```

Comment: You dont need it but https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/54954/why-use-where-1-or-where-1-1

Comment: Thanks Caldazar!  The group by is the problem.  The 1=1 is used in the app where the code will be placed as it is MS Vista and additional where clauses are always adding from the GUI with an "and" at the beginning.  The 1=1 is superfluous in "regular" SQL.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Glad it helped. Would appreciate if you mark it as answer :)

Comment: Accepted the answer.  Thanks again.